# Count of cases per group, based on a min value of another variable, also per same groups

Tags: r, dplyr

**I have the following type of dataframe:**

```
Person General_Type Specific_Type Age
  A         X            XY        2
  A         Y            YZ        3
  A         Y            YY        3
  B         X            XY        5
  B         Y            YZ        6
  B         X            XX        8
```

**What I am trying to do:**

For each person separately, I want to calculate the age where he first produces a Specific_Type YZ.

Then, I want to count all the cases where he produces a General_Type X, up to the age which I calculated earlier.

**What I have so far:**

The original data is in the dataframe 'data_file'.

I've managed to get the age using:

```
Person <- c('A', 'B')
df <- data.frame(Person)

library(dplyr)

Initial_Age <- (data_file %>% 
        group_by_(.dots=c("Person","Specific_Type")) %>% 
        filter(all(Specific_Type == "YZ")) %>% 
        summarize(Age_Calc = min(Age)))
df$Initial_Age <- Initial_Age$Age_Calc
```

I can get the total count per Person for each General_Type using the following:

```
total_count <- (data_file %>% 
                 group_by(Person, General_Type) %>% 
                  filter(all(General_Type == "x")) %>% 
                 summarize(count = n()))
```

But I'm not sure how to use the results from the former in the latter.

**Specifically, what I am asking is how to calculate the count of General_Type X for each person, up to the age where he first produces a Specific_Type YZ.**

I am currently using dplyr, but am open to other solutions if they're preferable.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best title, but I could not find a better one myself. Feel free to edit or suggest a preferable alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
data_file %>% 
  group_by(Person) %>% 
  filter(Age <= first(Age[Specific_Type == "YZ"])) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(General_Type == "X"))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Person count
#    <chr> <int>
# 1      A     1
# 2      B     1
```

NB: If your data is not already sorted, use `min` instead of `first`.

**Data:**

```
data_file <- read.table(text = "
Person General_Type Specific_Type Age
  A         X            XY        2
  A         Y            YZ        3
  A         Y            YY        3
  B         X            XY        5
  B         Y            YZ        6
  B         X            XX        8
                        ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```